# How promises are resolved?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a script which executes a lot of promises. Basically my script, "Task", starts when a new record is added to the database. Based on this record I make a request to an API and get an array of results. I then save those results to the database. Then I use the same array of results to make a request per result to another api used to get images. Then all those images will be uploaded to S3.

So, for each task I execute, I trigger a lot of requests, queries to database, updates, etc. All of those are resolved in promises. So my question is, what's will happen if I insert many "Task" records into the database? What's the order for promise execution? Will the program wait until the first task (and sub-tasks) end? Or will the program throw results independently by task while other tasks are resolving too?

This is because I can't wait until all promises of first task have been resolved to start to execute the next task.

If you have some additional questions, just tell me, I can update the question.

Comment: The entire point of promises is that they're used in asynchronous operations. If they always executed sequentially you wouldn't need to use them. That said, it's pretty much impossible to say what your specific code does without seeing your code.

Comment: @German check my answer below if my answer helps, please upvote and mark as solved.

Comment: @GuyIncognito It's there a lot of code to explain my point. But I don't need promises resolved sequentially, I'm asking for parallel responses, not like stack, but I dont want to waits until the first task resolves to starts to resolve the next

Comment: Yes, that is what promises do by default and by definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation of your Task, `onRecordAddTask`. that clarifies the order for **promise** execution.

```js
const requestAPI = record => {/* make API request */}

const saveToDatabase = result => {/* save result to database */}

const getImages = apiResult => {/* make images API request */}

const flatten = arr => arr.flat(1)

const uploadToS3 = image => {/* upload to s3 code */}

const onRecordAddTask = async record => {
  const results = await requestAPI(record)
  const [arraysOfImages,] = await Promise.all([
    await Promise.all(results.map(getImages)),
    await Promise.all(results.map(saveToDatabase)),
  ])
  await Promise.all(flatten(arraysOfImages).map(uploadToS3))
}
```

`onRecordAddTask` should be called with each newly inserted record into your database. The task requests an API `requestAPI` with your record, and returns an array of `results`. Then, for each result of results we `saveToDatabase` while we `getImages` per result in parallel; we wait for images per result as `arraysOfImages`. Finally, we upload all images to s3 as `uploadToS3`.

I should mention that I wrote a library to handle complex async tasks such as yours; here is how you would simplify the above code with that library.

```js
const { pipe, fork, map, get } = require('rubico')

const onRecordAddTask = pipe([
  requestAPI,
  fork([
    map(getImages),
    map(saveToDatabase),
  ]),
  get(0),
  map(map(uploadToS3)),
])
```

> I can't wait until all promises of first task are been resolved to start to execute the latest task.

because `onRecordAddTask` returns a single promise, you are free to let it run away so that it does not block you from executing the latest task.

> what will happen if I insert many "Task" records on database

you will start off many executions of the task `onRecordAddTask`

Comment: Hey so many thanks, this is just like I resolved the question, you have done in the same way like me

Comment: glad to hear it, I tried to think from your perspective

Answer (score -2):

The short answer is: Yes

You can run all promises at the same time.

Use `Promise.all([])` and pass in an array of promises.

Your code will look like this:

```
async function main() {

    const promises = []
    for(const task of tasks){
        promises.push(task)
    }
    console.log('All promise at once')
    await Promise.all(promises)
    console.log('All promise at once done')
}
```

Comment: I think it does not answer my question, I do know what the `.all` method does. I don't want to wait until all promises are resolved, I want to bring responses to client when some task are done, but I don't want to wait until first tasks promises resolves